# Greek letter alpha in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, greek

I would like to print the Greek letter alpha in place of alpha1, alpha2 and alpha3. Ho do I do that?
Here is the code below:

```
\begin{center}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2, auto,swap]
\filldraw [black] (.7,3) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [black] (.8,3) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [black] (.9,3) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [black] (1,3) circle (1pt);
\filldraw [black] (1.1,3) circle (1pt);
\foreach \pos/\name/\disp in {
  {(0,4)/1/K}, 
  {(-2,3)/2/alpha1}, 
  {(0,3)/3/alpha2}, 
  {(2,3)/4/alpha3}}
\node[minimum size=20pt,inner sep=0pt] (\name) at \pos {\disp};
\foreach \source/\dest in {
  1/2,
  1/3,
  1/4}
\path[draw,thick,->] (\source) -- node {} (\dest);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX,SE! Tray `$\alpha$`.

Comment: Thank you, that worked.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is resolved in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is solved by (my) comment, so here is a off-topic suggestion. Your image remains to a tree. Trees can be simple drawn with TikZ:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % for \dotsm 

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node {$K$}
    child{ node {$\alpha_1$}}
    child{ node {$\alpha_2$}}
    child{ node {$\dotsm$} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    child{ node {$\alpha_n$}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]